# Showing RDLC header only one time

Tags: rdlc

Normally in RDLC reports, if you use a header it will be repeated on every page.

What's the solution if I only want to show the header on the first page and not the rest? Is there any way to tell the header on what pages to be visible?

Comment: As a responsible community member your 0% acceptable rate is poor..

Answer (score 9):

You can't do this with Page Headers.

You will need to move the header controls into your Body section in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

First remove page header.

If you want to display data in first page, then put the controls before the tablix control in the body only. If you want to display data in every page, set that control repeat with property to tablix.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it at the top of body above tablixes

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your page header contains a textbox along with an image. The best thing that you can do is to 
1.) Minimize the height of Page header(containing image and textbox) as small as you want to.

2.) Set the image size property to Original Size.

3.) Set the textbox size property sizing option to "Allow height Increase".

4.) Set the textbox font size property as =IIf(Globals!PageNumber <> 1 , "0pt", "12pt")

5.) Set the textbox and image visibility property to "=(Globals!PageNumber <> 1)"  this will hide your text and image on all other pages except page1.

Step 4 is optional.
All the Best